# Excel VBA ADODB Access Database Lookup - Reduce Query Time

Tags: excel, database, vba, ms-access, adodb

I've written some VBA code which queries an access database and pulls that code into the cells. It works, but is extremely slow, mostly down to the way I've written it, however I'm struggling to speed it up.

The first and second query are the same, except the second query has a 1 month offset.

How can I speed this up?

First issue is that I seem to have to connect and close the database each loop. If I try and run both queries within the same database connection I get an error.

Second issue is the join seems to be quite slow.

```
  ' FIRST MONTH QUERY
  db.Connect
     db.RunGetResults ("SELECT data.*, monthdata.VAL, monthdata.MONTHVAL, monthdata.GREEN, monthdata.RED, monthdata.RAG, monthdata.CREATOR FROM data LEFT JOIN monthdata ON data.UID = monthdata.DATAUID WHERE [UID] = '" & (IDcell) & "'  AND [MONTHVAL] = #" & Format(Range("multidate"), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#")
    'Debug.Print db.Recordset.RecordCount

            irow = IDcell.Row
            Do Until db.Recordset.EOF
            icol = 2
            For Each ifield In db.Recordset.Fields
            Sheet3.Cells(irow, icol) = ifield.Value
                icol = icol + 1
                Next
            i = i + 1
           progress i

            db.Recordset.MoveNext
            If db.Recordset.EOF = True Then
            Else
            End If
            Loop
        End If

    Next
    db.Disconnect

   GoTo 69

   ' SECOND MONTH QUERY
             For Each IDcell In Rng
            If IDcell <> "" Then
            db.Connect
            'Application.Goto Reference:="month2"
            db.RunGetResults ("SELECT monthdata.VAL, monthdata.MONTHVAL, monthdata.GREEN, monthdata.RED, monthdata.RAG, monthdata.CREATOR FROM data LEFT JOIN monthdata ON data.UID = monthdata.DATAUID WHERE [UID] = '" & (IDcell) & "'  AND [MONTHVAL] = #" & Format((month2), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#")

            'Debug.Print db.Recordset.RecordCount

            irow = IDcell.Row
            Do Until db.Recordset.EOF
            icol = 18
            For Each ifield In db.Recordset.Fields
            Sheet3.Cells(irow, icol) = ifield.Value
            icol = icol + 1
            Next
             i = i + 1
           progress i
            db.Recordset.MoveNext
            If db.Recordset.EOF = True Then
            Else
            End If
            Loop
        End If
    Next
    db.Disconnect
```

### Edit

On request this is the db object

```
Public WithEvents Connection As ADODB.Connection
Public WithEvents Recordset As ADODB.Recordset
Public Command As New ADODB.Command
Public FilePath
Public Password

Public Function Connect()

    If Connection.State = 1 Then Disconnect

   AccessConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & FilePath & "';Jet OLEDB:Database Password='" & Password & "';"

       Connection.ConnectionString = AccessConnect
       Connection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
       Connection.mode = adModeReadWrite
       Connection.Open

End Function

Public Function Disconnect()
    On Error Resume Next
    Connection.Close
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function RunGetResults(qryString)

    sqlQuery = qryString
    Recordset.Open sqlQuery, Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

End Function
Public Function Execute(qryString)

    Connection.Execute (qryString)

End Function

Public Function Esc(eString)
    eString = Replace(eString, "'", "''")
    Esc = eString
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
    Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset

    Password = "xxxxx"
End Sub
```

Comment: [`CopyFromRecordSet()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.CopyFromRecordset) is the fastest way to dump a database set to a range.  If the problem is the query performance then the first thing to do is to ensure you have appropriate indexes on the tables.

Comment: If there is a problem with the "`db`" object then you should edit & describe what it actually is.

Comment: @AlexK. Trouble is I don't want everything, I only want certain times which is why I want to use the query. Can I import selectively with CopyfromRecordSet()? We do have indexes on the table.

Comment: @AlexK. I put in the code for the DB object

Comment: You would pass it your db.Recordset - which contains the queried data - and it will dump it into the sheet without needing any manual looping.

Comment: Not sure why you are opening the connection in ReadWrite mode either, you're not updating anything in the database.

Comment: @Minty Would it be ```adMode = ReadOnly``` ?

Comment: Also note: `GoTo 69` is a sin, and you and future developers will get punished for using it. See https://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: On your "I seem to have to connect and close the database each loop" - have you tried `Db.Recordset.Close` to close the Recordset before you try to reuse it?  Also, have you used `Debug.Print "WhatAmIDoing: " & Format(Now(),"hh:mm:ss")` to track *which* lines are taking up the time?

Comment: And, what is `progress i` - is that supposed to be a Comment, or is it a sub/function you haven't included?  Because currently noting increments `irow`, so you're overwriting the same row with data again, and again, and again - just skip the `Do Until db.Recordset.EOF` and `db.Recordset.MoveNext`, and progress straight to `db.Recordset.MoveLast`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest only using `adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic` when you need it.

Locking and latching incurs overhead. If you're only going to read, use `adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly`. This doesn't lock the records, and doesn't require a continuous connection to receive updates when records get deleted.

Your entire database object seems weird to me. You're declaring the recordset and connection with events, but not listening to any events. This all incurs a bit of overhead.

You can also disconnect the recordset, but if you're using a static-type recordset with a read-only lock that'll likely not make much difference.